# Using data variable to affect dialog

Tags: jquery

I would like to have a dialog common to two different call-to-action buttons (row and not_row).  Each of the buttons would set a different data() variable.  Based on which variable is set, the dialog would react differently.

The following almost works.  Problem is that if row is first clicked, then not_row, $(this).data('row') remains set so the if statement doesn't act accordingly.  One option is to add another data variable in my click function such as data('type','row') and data('type','not_row'), but it seems like a waste.

Any suggestions?

http://jsfiddle.net/FYWY7/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Dialogs</title>
<link type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#not_row").click(function(){$("#dialog").data('id',$(this)).dialog("open");});
    $("#row").click(function(){$("#dialog").data('row',$(this)).dialog("open");});

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen    : false,
        resizable   : false,
        height      : 330,
        width       : 430, 
        modal       : true,
        buttons: [
        {
            text    : 'CLICK',
            click   : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                if($(this).data('row')) {alert('row');}
                else {alert('not row');}
            }
        }
        ]
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="row" id="row" data-bla="whatever" />
<input type="button" value="not_row" id="not_row" data-bla="whatever" />
<div id="dialog"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my solution.  The purpose of this script is to delete records. If on a main page, then pass the ID, delete the record, and reload the page. Or you might delete a row off a list, so pass the row which contains the ID as an attribute, delete the record, and remove the row from the DOM.  My solution was to check whether the passed variable was an object or a number (string).

PS.  Thanks Ravi

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Dialogs</title>
<link type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#not_row").click(function(){$("#dialog").data('id',$(this).attr('data-id')).dialog("open");});
    $("#row").click(function(){$("#dialog").data('row',$(this)).dialog("open");});

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen    : false,
        resizable   : false,
        height      : 330,
        width       : 430, 
        modal       : true,
        buttons: [
        {
            text    : 'CLICK',
            click   : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                if(typeof $(this).data('i') == "object") {alert('Delete record and delete row');}
                else {alert('Delete record and redirect');} 
            }
        }
        ]
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Delete Row" id="row" data-id='123' />
<input type="button" value="Delete ID" id="not_row" data-id='234' />
<div id="dialog"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass data to the open function of the dialog box like below code, and you can use `data-` attributes to pass the values. jquery [Data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method will read the values.

```
$('#row').click(function()
  {
     $("#dialog").data('id',$(this).data('row')).dialog('open'); 
  });

 $('#not_row').click(function()
  {
     $("#dialog").data('id',$(this).data('row')).dialog('open'); 
  });
```

working demo : [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FYWY7/9/)

Comment: You are passing the same data for both clicks - $(this).data('row').  I wish to pass either the actual id element or the actual row element.  The purpose of this script is to delete records.  If on a main page, then pass the ID, delete the record, and reload the page.  Or you might delete a row off a list, so pass the row which contains the ID as an attribute, delete the record, and remove the row from the DOM.

Comment: for that only i used data-Row, there you set your ID of the Row

Comment: I didn't expect data('id',$(this).data('row')) to work, but it does.  I would have thought it should be data('id',$(this).attr('data-row')).

Comment: @user1032531 no. data() method, does not need data- prefix. check the documentation, if it works accept the ans

Comment: Not solved.  I don't want to use the id or data-row to instruct the dialog to do one thing or the other.  I wish to have whether data('id') or data('row') is set by the click function.  Maybe an alternative approach will be to have both click functions set data("bla"), but the one previously setting id set it as a integer, and the one previously setting row setting it as an object.  Then the dialog would check if it is an integer or object.

Comment: Yea, the following works:   if(typeof $(this).data('i') == "object") {alert('row');} else {alert('not row');}